# 'BuildContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<Position>) Flutter

Tags: flutter

Noob here. I have been following some coding tutorial on youtube using geolocator plugin and the goal is to track and stream a moving device current location. I can't get it to work because of recent version changes not applying to the way it was coded on the videos. Aside from my very shallow understanding of streams in Flutter.

From my geolocator_service.dart class/file I would like to call and attach it to my map.dart screen file. But in building the widget I got stuck in the builder parameter of StreamBuilder:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:maglako/services/geolocator_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class Map extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {

  final GeolocatorService geolocatorService = GeolocatorService();

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder <Position> (
        stream: geolocatorService.getCurrentLocation(),
        builder: (context, snapshot)  //  <---- this is where the error is located
      ) ,

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My geolocator_service.dart file  (geolocator 7.1.0 plugin)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class GeolocatorService {
  final Geolocator geo = Geolocator();


  Stream<Position> getCurrentLocation()  {

    return Geolocator.getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,distanceFilter: 10);
  }
```

Would also appreciate if you can point me to a good tutorial on the subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this, the builder expect a widget, and in this widget you can draw what you need to show to the user, like lat and lang as text or a custom widget, snapshot will show you the data you need

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder <Position> (
        stream: geolocatorService.getCurrentLocation(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
            // Updated
            return Text('Data updated');
          }
        ) ,
      ),
    );
  }
```